# Paying bills by bank account

Tags: bank-account, billing

I paid the bill by bank account on nov.11. It has been 4 days but the payment wasn't recorded on checking acc yet. Should i call the bank or wait a few more days?

Comment: Does the bill show as being paid (not on the bill pay web site, but on the web site of the company you owe the money)?  I ask because you might have configured something incorrectly.

Comment: Did you enter the information at the bank or at the vendor? It can make a difference.

Comment: @RonJohn I can only see the amount of money (current balance) and on the bank account information it's written (active)

Comment: @mhoran_psprep It was on the web actually, on their website.

Comment: I'd call the company you owe the money to and ask if they've received payment.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the bank; for example Bank of America deducts it from the checking account on (business!) day 5 (which is the day the check typically arrives at the recipient); Chase deducts it the day it gets sent out.
Your bank might be somewhere inbetween (or outside).

I would wait until 5 business days have passed at least before you start worrying - that means a full week after you submitted it, plus potentially the next day, if you submitted outside of banking hours.

Comment: Thank you Aganju for the information  it's my first time using  bank account because of that i was worried.